# Why when I use belongsToMany relation between two table not get the data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

Get data through `belongsToMany` relation between the tables:

**Users Model:**

```
public function  favorites()
{
    return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\job', 'favourites', 'user_id', 'job_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Job Model:**

```
public function  favorites()
{
    return $this
            ->belongsToMany(job::class, 'favourites', 'job_id', 'user_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs = Auth::user()->favorites;

    return view('home',compact('jobs'));
}
```

Nothing appears  any errors and any data.

Comment: Sidenote: `'App\job'` should be `'App\Job'` or `Job::class`; Model names are uppercase (`class Job extends Model { ... }` and `Job.php`).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Job` model. Your relationship is pointing to the same (Job) model. Change it to this:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this
            ->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourites', 'job_id', 'user_id')        
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: the same problem